# mysql: Restore backup that was created with "--tab" option in mysqldump

Tags: mysql

mysqldump has the "--tab" option to split up the dump separate files for each table. mysql creates a .sql file (with schema) and a .txt file (with data) for each table.

The .sql files work fine, but how do I import the data from the .txt files?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL Workbench ? http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/, has some nice functionality for backups and restoring your data

Comment: Could you show how one of this .txt files looks like?

Comment: it's a CSV file using tabs, that's all. You'll have to use `load data infile` with the appropriate settings.

Answer (score 4):

Official documentation doesn't covert the case of importing these `*.txt` and foreign key constrains. There is still open long-lived [bug#19996](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19996) to implement foreign key ignore in `mysqlimport`. So it has to be done manually.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

DIR=/path/to/csv/backup
DATABASE=database
USER=user
PASSWORD=password

for filename in $DIR/*.txt
do
tablename=`basename $filename .txt`
mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD $DATABASE <<EOF
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
  LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE \`$tablename\`;
EOF
done
```

Also I would like to note that there's no much sense in storing these per-table `*.sql` files produced by `mysqldump --tab`, because there's also a foreign key issue on fields. As a schema is always known I suggest just to delete them after backup is completed.